# undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Destroy'

Tags: c++, azure, azure-iot-hub, arduino-esp8266, azure-iot-sdk

I was compiling the iothub_ll_telemetry_sample from the examples of the AzureIotHub library for arduino. i followed the instruction shown on [Azure/azure-iot-arduino](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino) github page.

After i entered `-DDONT_USE_UPLOADTOBLOB -DUSE_BALTIMORE_CERT` to the `platform.txt` like this `build.extra_flags=-DESP8266 -DDONT_USE_UPLOADTOBLOB -DUSE_BALTIMORE_CERT`, i compiled the code and got this error on the arduino IDE

```
c:/users/abhij/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: libraries\AzureIoTHub\iothub_client_core_ll.c.o: in function `delete_event_callback_list':

C:\Users\abhij\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/iothub_client_core_ll.c:1174: undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Destroy'

c:/users/abhij/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: libraries\AzureIoTHub\iothub_client_core_ll.c.o: in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_Destroy':

C:\Users\abhij\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/iothub_client_core_ll.c:1729: undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Destroy'

c:/users/abhij/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: libraries\AzureIoTHub\iothub_client_core_ll.c.o:(.text.initialize_iothub_client+0x60): undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Create'

c:/users/abhij/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: libraries\AzureIoTHub\iothub_client_core_ll.c.o: in function `initialize_iothub_client':

C:\Users\abhij\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/iothub_client_core_ll.c:773: undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Destroy'

c:/users/abhij/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\abhij\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/iothub_client_core_ll.c:872: undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Create'

c:/users/abhij/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\abhij\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/iothub_client_core_ll.c:905: undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Destroy'

c:/users/abhij/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: libraries\AzureIoTHub\iothub_client_core_ll.c.o: in function `create_blob_upload_module':

C:\Users\abhij\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/iothub_client_core_ll.c:383: undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_Destroy'

c:/users/abhij/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: libraries\AzureIoTHub\iothub_client_core_ll.c.o: in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_CreateFromConnectionString':

C:\Users\abhij\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/iothub_client_core_ll.c:1454: undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_SetOption'

c:/users/abhij/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: libraries\AzureIoTHub\iothub_client_core_ll.c.o: in function `IoTHubClientCore_LL_SetOption':

C:\Users\abhij\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/iothub_client_core_ll.c:1558: undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_SetOption'

c:/users/abhij/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/esp8266/tools/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc/2.5.0-4-b40a506/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\abhij\Documents\Arduino\libraries\AzureIoTHub\src/iothub_client_core_ll.c:2310: undefined reference to `IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_SetOption'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```